# What does it mean to be a Ninja Assassin?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

While playing Halo: The Master Chief Collection, I came across a mode in the Team Action Sack playlist called Ninja Assassins. It's a slayer type game in which the player is given a sniper rifle, an energy sword, and the boost armor ability, and the mini-map is disabled. The objective is to become the deadliest ninja, but all it is, is a team slayer game. At the bottom of the screen while playing however, there is a ninja level counter with 1-3 out of 3. This count goes up when you get a kill, but seems to have no real significance. Is it pointless or does it have a cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually a couple of stats that get boosted depending on your Ninja Level.

> Ninja Level 1
>
> - Shields recharge at a faster rate (2x)
> - Assassinations performed at a faster rate (2x)
>
> Ninja Level 2
>
> - Shields recharge at a faster rate (2x)
> - Shields recharge sooner than normal (after 3 seconds)
> - Assassinations performed at a faster rate (3x)
>
> Ninja Level 3
>
> - Shields recharge at a faster rate (2x)
> - Shields recharge sooner than normal (after 2 seconds)
> - Assassinations performed at a faster rate (4x)
> - Unlimited Thruster Pack energy

[Source](https://www.vg247.com/2014/04/15/halo-4-gets-ninja-assassin-playlist/)